# How to update lecture #2 code to work with newer versions of Plutus?

Tags: plutus-pioneer-program

I've been trying to load solution #1 for week 2 of PPP into the public Plutus playground here: https://playground.plutus.iohkdev.io/

and I get several errors :/

[image]

[image]

I am absolutely perplexed. Does anyone know why newer versions of Plutus are having issues with this endpoint code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I made a walk-through video for that: https://youtu.be/UbTOZWr1-yM

And a corresponding Github repo: https://github.com/manonthemat/GiftContract-109

Comment: OMG thank you! This is so much better than what I was looking for haha